# Derive the transition table for the following AB latch. Describe how it functions

Tags: latch

I have no idea where to start or how to do this.......I have tried using the charactiresic equation of an SR latch, $$Q^+ = S +R'Q$$ and derive the equation for S and R from the drawing, with no success.....

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That circuit looks unstable. When A=B=0, it oscillates. When A=B=1, it stabilizes in the reset state. The other two inputs seem to produce illegal conditions where both S and R are high. Perhaps the question wants a transition table that shows the oscillation.

Comment: what about when Q = 0, AB=10 and when Q=1, AB= 01. they seem to be an allowed states that gives Q+ =0

Comment: When AB=01 and Q=1, the latch will be reset. (The bottom gate is an OR, not an XOR). This makes S=1 while R=1, which is illegal. AB=10 and Q=0 is a stable state, but you can't reliably get there unless you start out with AB=11. Otherwise, you might set AB=10 while Q=1, which makes S=R=1.